# I am trying to get a slider to work and I keep getting outputUpdate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a slider to work and I keep getting outputUpdate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput.

My HTML is:

```js
function outputUpdate(mil) {
  document.querySelector('#mileage').value = mil;
};
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="10" ng-model="miles" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
<output for="fader" id="mileage">25</output>
<label for="fader">miles</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do with `this.value` `oninput="outputUpdate(this.value)"`

```js
function outputUpdate(mil) {
        document.querySelector('#mileage').value = mil;
    };
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="10" ng-model="miles" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(this.value)">
<output for="fader" id="mileage">25</output>
<label for="fader">miles</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherit problem with your code. See this codepen with your html and javascript working as expected: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZLRwg

Because of this, the problem is likely that your javascript is not in the correct spot so that it is visible to the `<input>` tag that is looking for it.